# Получение данных из функции на блок-схеме

Tags: алгоритм, блок-схема

Возник вопрос о реализации ввода данных в отдельно написанную функцию на блок-схеме. Можете подсказать как это сделать??? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Нужно ввести пару чисел в функцию и получить на выходе результат. Ввод цифр (в виде аргументов), производится в основном блоке программы. Как это реализовать  в блок-схеме пока не знаю @AK

Comment: Ввод данных на блок-схемах изображается паралелограммом, об этом написано на каждом заборе. [тынц1](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D1%81%D1%85%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0) и [тынц2](https://pro-prof.com/archives/1462). Рисуете паралелограм, в нём пишете "ввести x,y". Об этом вопрос? Или у вас нужна отдельная блок-схема для отдельной функции и вам нужно указать, что у функции два входных параметра?

Comment: Да, мне нужна именно отдельная блок-схема, для отдельной функции, с указанием, что у функции два входных параметра. Я так понял, что это реализуется не простым вводом данных @AK

Comment: В блок схемах есть подпрограммы (прямоугольник с двумя параллельно вертикальными прямыми всередини) это отвам и нужно.